# How to remove a specific word with special charecters from a String?

Tags: android, regex, string

After some reference I'm able to remove particular word from a `string` .But I wonder why words with special charecters are not removed .

Code:

```
String txt = "It is an @example example";
String regex = "\\s*\\b@example\\b\\s*";
String finalSt = txt.replaceAll(regex, "");
demoTxt.setText(finalSt);
```

The desired output is: `It is an example`

But the output is: `It is an @example example`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `\\b` is a word boundary, which matches the end of word. The word consists of `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, or `_` characters. `@` is not a word character. You may rewrite your regexp like this, but it depends of your needs:

```
String regex = "\\s*@example\\s*";
String finalSt = txt.replaceAll(regex, " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be your regex: "\s*\b*@example\b\s*" OR "\s*@example\b\s*"

Those examples will remove the space too.